# For Loop Skips last List

Tags: python, for-loop, xlsxwriter, xlwings

I have a for loop statement that when executes always creates one less excel than the list has. However when the first part of the if statement is used (xlwings, to modify the existing excels it works fine) Thoughts?

```
names= list(df_ora['XCODE'].unique())
for prov in names:
    #for each matching agency code we create a df2
    df2 = df_ora[df_ora['CODE'].isin([prov,'00000'])]
   # create a filename to verify the excel exisits
    filename = (dir_src  + '\\' + str(prov) + '_' + 'Claims' + '.xlsx')
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        wb = xw.Book(filename)
        ws = wb.sheets['DATA']
        ws.clear_contents()
        ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df2
        ws.autofit()
        wb = xw.Book(filename)
        wb.save()
        xw.apps[0].quit()
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')  
        df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DATA',index=False)
        counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try closing the writer, or `writer.save()`, right after `df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DATA',index=False)`. The writer's content is probably not flushed to disk until it's either explicitly closed or goes out of scope.